# What does underscore stand for in this code

Tags: scheme, racket

How does following code work? This code is from Racket documentation [https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html?q=2d%20renderers#%28part.*2.D*.Line_.Renderers%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html?q=2d%20renderers#%28part._2.D_.Line_.Renderers%29) (see function points on this page). This is not usual function definition statement. What does the underscore stand for here?

```
(define xs (build-list 5 (λ _ (random))))
```

The xs gets following value:

```
> xs
'(0.9520057193043618 0.1339193598495859 0.0019128879992944899 0.7511052254656998 0.4442323053722083)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda can either have a list of identifiers as parameter names (such as `(lambda (a b c) the-body )`) or a single identifier (such as `(lambda args the-body)`, which will then hold the list of all arguments.

The function given to `build-list` takes one parameter (the current index). It is customary to name parameters `_` when you don't intend to use their value.

So since we don't care about the current index when creating a random list, the parameter is named `_`. This could also be written as `(lambda (_)`, but since we don't care about any of the (one) parameters, we can just write `(lambda _` as well.

Comment: This basically is running (random) 20 times. The index it is getting each time is varying and is ignored.